# Django FileResponse with Reportlab downloading to the current directory instead of asking user to download

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I have a `reportlab` implementation that generates pdf files for users to view and download to their system but instead, the download is automatically done to my current directly where I am running the Django server from.

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    buff = io.BytesIO()
    invoice_name = "new_invoice.pdf"
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(invoice_name)

    flowables = []
    flowables.append(all_flowable_data)
    doc.build(flowables)
    buff.seek(0)
    return FileResponse(as_attachment=True, filename=invoice_name)
```

Once I click on the `Download Invoice` link, it just displays a blank page and when I check the current directory, the file is downloaded there.